# Why does Google want a vertical scrollbar on search page when it's not necessary

Tags: website-design, css

On [Google's search page](http://www.google.com) there is a visible vertical scroll bar even when it is not necessary. This can be avoided by deleting the following style from `body` selector

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

When this is done, there is no vertical scroll bar on default and when the height of browser window is not enough to display entire content, vertical scroll bar appears. Since Google is known  for their obsession with minimalism on their search page, why aren't they doing this?

I tested this behavior on Chromium 18 (ubuntu), Firefox 13 (ubuntu) and Internet Explorer 8 (winxp).

Comment: Normally I would've guessed that they want to avoid horizontal shifting that would occur when the page gets more content and scrollbar appears. The thing is, the way elements are placed in the page, the shifting really does not have much of an effect. Conclusion: Beats me.

Comment: Another thought: minimialism isn't just *less things*, it's less elements that could take attention. You could argue that an unusual empty space becoming a scrollbar is more of a distraction than a redundant scrollbar, since the scrollbar is part of the furniture, something people expect, are used to and filter out.

Comment: Re the horizontal shift theory: google's autocomplete options used to appear on the main Google page: this could have caused a scrollbar to appear making the centre-aligned logo jump jarringly to the side. It's possible they made the change then for that reason, and kept it the way it is for the other reason (or inertia).

Comment: @Joonas I agree, but there doesn't seem to be any another point in this. I guess Google made the trade off as user568458 explained and went with the default visible scrollbar.

Comment: @user568458 I think your first argument explains it well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joonas nailed it in the first comment. All except his concolusion: "Beats me".

True, small horizontal the shift isn't much, but google isn't going to let your browser mess with it's aesthetic. Not even a little. In fact, if play with your window size on their main page, you'll find some layout shifting **does** happen, but only when they want it to, and the shifting is equally divided between the right and left margins so it is less noticeable.

Horizontal shift theory resources

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/force-vertical-scrollbar/

http://www.websitecamp.com/css-code-to-force-browser-to-always-show-vertical-scrollbar

Comment: The horizontal shift has the potential to be quite distracting when using "Google Instant" feature, which shows search results as you type them.  If your browser was open to a certain height, it could constantly show, hide, and show the scroll bar as the results grew and shrunk just a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

The scrollbar doesn't appear on Mac + Chrome 21. Looks like something they've done to make the search results appear to be more responsive & quick.